# Synchronising two MySql tables, omitting certain columns

Tags: mysql, sql, synchronization, amazon-rds

I have two matching tables - one on an RDS database (master) and another on a standard MySql DB.  I want them synchronised, *except* that I don't want data from three of the columns to appear on the slave version.

mk-table-sync supposedly does this via its --columns option, however it's ignoring me and syncing everything. Tried many different options, including pt-table-sync and also removing those columns from the slave table, but not getting anywhere. Advice?

Example sync command, it's ignoring the columns request:

```
/usr/local/bin/mk-table-sync --columns columnA, columnB, columnC --execute  h=XXX,u=XXX,p=XXX,D=XXX,t=tableA h=XXX,D=XXX,t=tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation the `--columns` argument only says which columns should be compared. There is also `--ignore-columns` but it only ignore columns for comparison not from copying... Your task seems unrealizable with this tool.

Master - slave replication model is not intended to do column filter... What about using views for hiding that columns?

Comment: Thanks for explaining `--columns` - at least now I know why it's not working as I thought it would.  

re: views, I don't want all the data present on the slave database so it seems that a view wouldn't work for me as I can't sync a view to another database.  

Any other suggestions beyond changing the table structure?